# if command in LaTeX to choose path depending on the system

Tags: windows, input, mac

I'm running TeX on both my Windows computer, and my Mac, with the same preamble placed on both computers, but on different paths.

Would it somehow be possible to have a code that can automatically input my preamble located in the right path on my Windows, and the right path on my Mac?

Something like the following, even though it has nothing to do with LaTeX:

```
if(system=Windows)]\input {c:\\premable.tex}]
if(system=OSX)]\input {../user/premable.tex}]
```

Comment: There is a ifplatform package but it is much better to do what David suggest.

Comment: note that if you do use a path,  in windows tex implementations you should use `/` not `\\ ` to specify the path components.  In the argument of `\input` `\\ ` would expand to the command to start a new line and so generate weird internal errors.

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
 \input{preamble}
```

or better, rename the file from `premable.tex` to `preamble.sty` and use

```
\usepackage{preamble}
```

You don't need to use the path, just as you don't use the full path when including standard packages such as `inputenc`.

Then you just need to put the file in the input path on both machines, so the same folder as the document or in a folder specified by TEXINPUTS by default texlive includes a local folder for this reason. the location depends on the platform, in my cygwin installation that is a normal TDS tree `~/texmf` so I'd put it in

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/mypreamble/preamble.sty
```

If you want to place the file in pre-existing locations that is also OK, but just edit the `texmf.cnf` file to set `$TEXINPUTS` to include the location where you put the file.

```
kpsewhich texmf.cnf
```

will show you the location of this control file.

Answer (score 1):

Put the preambles in `$TEXINPUTS` directories is just the right way, but in case that you want maintain preambles in other places, one alternative is `\IfFileExists` to check if some concrete `/path/preamble.tex` exist. The next example make a nested checking and add some text according the preamble in use. If none of both preambles are found, is compiled only a error message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{/pathA/preamble.tex}%
{\input{/pathA/preamble}\AtEndDocument{the A preamble.}}%
{\IfFileExists{/pathB/preamble.tex}%
{\input{/pathB/preamble}\AtEndDocument{the B preamble.}}%
{\AtBeginDocument{\Huge\bfseries I need a preamble!!\end{document}}}}
\begin{document}
Hello ! I have 
\end{document}
```

Of course, change `/pathA/` and `/pathB/` with the real paths of your hard disk and put something different in both preambles (the `bookman` font in one preamble and the `electrum` font in the other, for instance) for a easier check of the result.